# flex 4: window system development ideas

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

My application will need some windows but I can't use the popUpManager to handle custom components so I'm thinking to implement a new window system.

But I still don't know how to merge it with my custom components. Any ideas?

My code:

My login skin:

```
<s:Skin(...)>
   <s:Group>
      (...login components...)
   </s:Group>
</s:Skin>


package com.totty.app.components.login {
import com.totty.app.TottysBrain;
import com.totty.app.components.window.Window;
import com.totty.app.events.LoginSuccessEvent;
import com.totty.tottysBrain.components.BrainyDynComponent;
import com.totty.tottysBrain.components.BrainyWindow;

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

import spark.components.Button;
import spark.components.CheckBox;
import spark.components.Group;
import spark.components.Label;
import spark.components.TextInput;
import spark.components.supportClasses.SkinnableComponent;

[Event(name="loginSuccess", type="com.totty.app.events.LoginSuccessEvent")]
public class Login extends BrainyDynComponent {
    [SkinPart(required="true")]
    public var email:TextInput;

    [SkinPart(required="true")]
    public var password:TextInput = new TextInput();

    [SkinPart(required="false")]
    public var rememberMe:CheckBox;

    [SkinPart(required="false")]
    public var notification:Label;

    [SkinPart(required="true")]
    public var submit:Button = new Button();

    private var _currentState:uint = 0;
    private var _states:Array = ['default', 'logging', 'loginFailure', 'loginSuccess'];

    private var _default:Boolean = false;
    private var _logging:Boolean = false;
    private var _loggingSuccess:Boolean = false;
    private var _loggingFailure:Boolean = false;

    public function Login() {
        super();

        defaultCommand = 'users.login';
        defaultSkin = LoginSkin;

        _setCurrentState(0);

        onPartAdded('submit', function():void {
                submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _submitLoginButton_click);
        });

        onPartRemoved('submit', function():void {
                submit.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _submitLoginButton_click);
        });

        onPartAdded('window', function():void{
            //window.addEventListener('close', _window_close);
            //window.title = 'Login';
        });
    }

    private function _window_close(evt:Event):void{
        dispatchEvent(evt);

        var parentAsGroup:Group = parent as Group
        parentAsGroup.removeElement(this);
    }

    protected function _submitLogin():void {
        _setCurrentState(1);
        submitData({email:email.text, password:password.text, rememberMe:rememberMe.selected});
    }

    override protected function _onSuccess(result:*):void {
        Alert.show(result);
        _setCurrentState(3);
        if(result) {
            dispatchEvent(new LoginSuccessEvent(email.text, rememberMe.selected));
            _loggingSuccess = true;
        }else{
            _setCurrentState(4);
            _loggingSuccess = false;
        }
    }

    override protected function _onFailure(result:*):void {
        Alert.show(result);
        _setCurrentState(4);
        _loggingSuccess = false;
    }

    private function _submitLoginButton_click(evt:MouseEvent):void {
        _submitLogin();
    }

    private function _setCurrentState(n:uint):void{
        if(_currentState == n) return;

        _currentState = n;
        invalidateProperties();
    }

    override protected function commitProperties():void{
        super.commitProperties();




        switch(_currentState){
            case 0:
                // default
                //window.footerText = '';
            break;
            case 1:
                // logging
                //window.footerText = 'logging';
            break;
            case 2:
                // loginFailure
                //window.footerText = 'loginFailure';
            break;
            case 3:
                // loginSuccess
                //window.footerText = 'loginSuccess';
                //parentBrain.removeElement(this);
                //var parentAsGroup:Group = parent as Group
                //PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
                //parentAsGroup.removeElement(this);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}`

Now I have the main application to add this component in a window. I would prefer to be able to be able to see the window while I'm designing the interface. That means that the window component must be added to the component. Not to use the  but something like  to contain all the contents of the component.

Comment: This is a pretty subjective question.  Maybe you should quantify what features your new window system needs to have and why you're having trouble merging it w/ custom components.

Comment: because I can't use my components made in as3 + mxml skin with titleWindow. I got errors, I have another question, and I can't solve it with the answers :s. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535707/flex-4-title-window-custom-component-skin-problem)
Features could be very basic, close, drag and drop and resize. Then the possibility to add minimize and a bar containing the minimized windows just like in WIN XP or vista. not that graphics of course, lighter.

Comment: Dear Totty, in your previous question, you got answer, imho its true answer, if you really want more help, just post somewhere/here example classes, so community could provide help based on your code. :)
thanks!

Comment: I have edited my original question and I added the source code. the mxml can't be written so it is very basic..

Comment: what is this BrainyDynComponent ? Could you make it extended from MDIWindow? or make work as interface?

Comment: Sorry for the long time to reply, but i had problems with my pc :s now i do not have this class anymore but i have the BaseView that extends the SkinnableContainer class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you already saw this, but its a good place to start, anyway :)

http://code.google.com/p/flexmdi/